# Chrome dev cant paste elements and F8 doesnt pause anymore

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can ctrl+c an element when it's selected but I can't paste it inside the dev tools html anymore(I can paste it elsewhere fine)? I've been doing it constantly suddenly I cant. Have I disabled it somehow or chromes new update changed something?

Second thing sometimes when element only appeared when it was javascript mousehover, I used F8 button to pause the whole site/js and the elemenent stayed in place, so I could style it visually, but this also has stopped working some time ago even, I just didnt need to use it as often.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your first problem, just do right-click and then `Edit as HTML`. For second one you need a breakpoint in your js code.

Comment: @Edwin have you done the copy paste element before did it work? Does it now? I dont understand what changed, it was very simple before. You have container with one box element in it ubt needs to have three so you just select it copy and select container and ctrl+v to see how it fits - very straightforward.